# What is the best way to retrieve gross sales of a certain product using Shopify API?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

What is the best way to retrieve gross sales of a certain product using Shopify API?

Comment: What language are you using? So I can use the right example.

Comment: Hi,  @FabioFilippi. I'm using Node.js.